# Sorting a List with a Another Sorted List

Tags: code-golf

Say i have a list (unorder):

```
Score = ['score1','score10','score6','score2','score22','score12']
Names = ['name1','name10','name6','name2','name22','name12']
email = ['email1','email10','email6','email2','email22','email12']
```

and then Score is sorted to be

```
ScoreSorted = ['score1','score2','score6','score10','score12','score22'].
```

The shortest code (in byte) to sort Name and Email with Score list wins

result of email and names list should be

```
EmailSorted = ['email1','email2','email6','email10','email12','email22'].
NamesSorted = ['name1','name2','name6','name10','name12','name22'].
```

Comment: It's not clear whether you're expecting `ScoreSorted` to be input, output, or neither.

Comment: So, we have a list `A`, and a list `A'` which is a permutation of `A`, and then for a given list `B` we should find the same permutation `B'`?

Comment: @marinus I interpretted the problem as the following: given a list `A` with a logical lexicographical ordering, sort this list, and apply the same permutation to both `B` and `C`. This is analogous to sorting data rows in a spreadsheet by a specific column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Ruby 81 bytes

```
m=Score.each_index.sort_by{|i|Score[i]}
p m.map{|i|Names[i]}
p m.map{|i|Email[i]}
```

A golfed implemention of the algorithm below, assuming `Score`, `Names`, and `Email` are all already defined, and that only output of the post-sorted `Names` and `Email` is required.

Sample usage:

```
Score = ['score1','score10','score6','score2','score22','score12']
Names = ['name1','name10','name6','name2','name22','name12']
Email = ['email1','email10','email6','email2','email22','email12']

m=Score.each_index.sort_by{|i|Score[i]}
p m.map{|i|Names[i]}
p m.map{|i|Email[i]}
```

Sample output:

```
["name1", "name10", "name12", "name2", "name22", "name6"]
["email1", "email10", "email12", "email2", "email22", "email6"]
```

---

### Ruby (with natural sort) 123 bytes

```
m=Score.each_index.sort_by{|i|Score[i].scan(/\d+|\D+/).map{|i|i=~/\d/?i.to_i: i}}
p m.map{|i|Names[i]}
p m.map{|i|Email[i]}
```

Correctly sorts strings with any number of digital groupings, as one would sort them 'naturally'. The only caveat is that all strings in the `Score` array must start with a digit, or all must start with a non-digit.

Sample output:

```
["name1", "name2", "name6", "name10", "name12", "name22"]
["email1", "email2", "email6", "email10", "email12", "email22"]
```

---

### Python

Not a code-golf answer.

1. Find the inverse permutation of the list which is to be sorted in lexicographical order (in the problem description, this `Scores` array). This can be achieved in *O(n log n)* time (as the problem is analog to sorting), although the implementation below is *O(n²)*.
2. Apply this permutation to each list. The permute function is *O(n)* complexity.

Sample implementation:

```
def get_inv_perm(items):
  size = len(items)
  perm = [0]*size
  for i in range(size):
    for j in range(size): perm[j] += items[j] > items[i]
  return perm

def permute(arr, perm):
  size = len(arr)
  out = [0] * size
  for i in range(size):
    val = perm[i]
    out[i] = arr[val]
  return out

if __name__ == "__main__":
  Score = ['score1','score10','score6','score2','score22','score12']
  Names = ['name1','name10','name6','name2','name22','name12']
  Email = ['email1','email10','email6','email2','email22','email12']

  perm = get_inv_perm(Score)

  print permute(Score, perm)
  print permute(Names, perm)
  print permute(Email, perm)
```

Sample output:

```
['score1', 'score10', 'score12', 'score2', 'score22', 'score6']
['name1', 'name10', 'name12', 'name2', 'name22', 'name6']
['email1', 'email10', 'email12', 'email2', 'email22', 'email6']
```

Because the sort is lexicographical, `score10` and `score12` appear directly after `score1`. The `get_inv_perm` function assumes the items list is unique. The remaining lists need not be.

Answer (score 1):

Python, 172 bytes. Assumes names and emails are unique. Not particularly efficient as you have to do a lookup for each comparison.

```
NamesSorted=sorted(Names,lambda l,r:cmp(Score[Names.index(l)],Score[Names.index(r)]))
EmailSorted=sorted(email,lambda l,r:cmp(Score[email.index(l)],Score[email.index(r)]))
```

Answer (score 1):

**Ruby** 108 bytes

```
[names, email, score].map do |z|
  z.sort! {|x, y| x.scan(/\d/).join.to_i <=> y.scan(/\d/).join.to_i }
end
puts "#{names}\n#{email}\n#{score}"
```

Answer (score 1):

### C++ 117 bytes

```
#define S(a)a##Sorted.push_back(a[i])
for(auto a:ScoreSorted){int i=0;for(auto b:Score)a==b?S(Names),S(Email),0:++i;}
```

Notice that I am making two assumptions:

- strings vectors for to represent all lists
- it is OK to capitalize the name of the unsorted email list (email -> Email)

Sample usage:

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<string> Score = {"score1","score10","score6","score2","score22","score12"};
    vector<string> Names = {"name1","name10","name6","name2","name22","name12"};
    vector<string> Email = {"email1","email10","email6","email2","email22","email12"};

    vector<string> ScoreSorted = {"score1","score2","score6","score10","score12","score22"};
    vector<string> NamesSorted;
    vector<string> EmailSorted;

#define S(a)a##Sorted.push_back(a[i])
for(auto a:ScoreSorted){int i=0;for(auto b:Score)a==b?S(Names),S(Email),0:++i;}

    for (auto i : NamesSorted) {
        cout << i << endl;
    }
    for (auto i : EmailSorted) {
        cout << i << endl;
    }
}
```